# Qgis 3.0 migration pyrcc5 issue

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have my plugin which works for QGIS 2.8.2.
I want to migrate the same for QGIS 3.0. I resolved initial error of pyqt4 to pyqt5 and so on.

Now I get following error for resources file.

```
TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, bytes, bytes, bytes): argument 2 has
 unexpected type 'str'
```

My existing resource file is compiled with pyrcc4 command. I need to compile it again with pyrcc5 command.

I went to my plugin folder from command prompt and did

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc

'pyrcc5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have pyrcc5.bat in "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.0\apps\Python36\Scripts"
When I try to run this batch file I get:

[image]

pyrcc5.exe not found anywhere in the folder.